# Summary of values in a given field

Tags: filemaker

I have a field [values] where a range of values (say A - E) can be added. Viewed across a number of records we get something like

Record 1 [values] A

Record 2 [values]

Record 3 [values] A

Record 4 [values] C

Record 5 [values] B

Is there a way of producing a summary field of [values] where the above would return :

A

B

C

my thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you want with a Value List:

1. Make a new value list labeled 'Values' (File Menu > Manage > Value Lists)
2. Make the value list 'Use Values From Field' and specify your Values field
3. Create a new Calculation field, 'Listed Values'
4. Set the calculation to type 'Text' and with the following code:

`ValueListItems ( Get(FileName) ; "Values" )`

You will likely want to turn on "Do Not Store Calculation Results" for the Listed Values field.